# Why is Serbia not among selectable countries in Salesforce.com?

Tags: community, partner-communities, country-and-state

So I decided to join `Salesforce Partner Community`, however, I can't complete my application as I'm from Serbia and there's no `Serbia` as an option among the list of available countries. Does anybody know why is that and if there are other missing countries as well?

I also found [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aFk9AAE) old request on `Idea Exchange`, so if people reading my question could cast their vote I guess that would help too.

Thank you!

Comment: Although I don't know for sure, I'd say it's likely just because Salesforce doesn't/can't support every single language & region. I'd expect if enough interest was shown from native Serbian speakers, it's soon get ratified through.

Comment: I understand that they can't support every single language & region, and I'm actually not expecting them to support Serbian language. When I go to create my partner community profile there are 15 supported languages, which is completely fine. However, what I don't understand is why there's no Serbia in a list of countries, and that list, on first glance, consists of all other countries in the World - certainly 100+ countries.